# String to array of numbers in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, highcharts

I have a string containing following data:

```
6,11,32,110,235,369,640,1005,1436,2063,3057,4618,6444,9822,15468,20434,24126,27387,29459,31056,31982,32040,31233,29224,27342,26662,26956,27912,28999,28965,27826,25579,25722,24826,24605,24304,23464,23708,24099,24357,24237,24401,24344,23586,22380,21004,17287,14747,13076,12555,12144,11009,10950,10871,10824,10577,10527,10475,10421,10358,10295,10104
```

basically i am reading this string from a file, i want to pass it on to the data of a series in highchart. when i do data:(above mentioned string), no data gets displayed, maybe because it is a string (even though everything gets declared as var). but when i declare an array of data myself like

```
var series = [6,11,32,110,235,369,640,1005,1436,2063,3057,4618,6444,9822,15468,20434,24126,27387,29459,31056,31982,32040,31233,29224,27342,26662,26956,27912,28999,28965,27826,25579,25722,24826,24605,24304,23464,23708,24099,24357,24237,24401,24344,23586,22380,21004,17287,14747,13076,12555,12144,11009,10950,10871,10824,10577,10527,10475,10421,10358,10295,10104];
```

It displays the data on to the chart. So kindly tell me how to convert the string i'm reading from file into the array of data i declared.

Comment: Your question would look better if you put your current file reading script...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Highcharts only accepts arrays of integers, you can split the string into an array and then use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to cast the strings either into integers or floating point numbers:

```
var arr = str.split(',').map(function (el) {
  return parseInt(el, 10);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/bqWdM/)

Comment: Or just `str.split(',').map(Number)`

Answer (score 1):

Use `.split` method:

```
> "6,11,32,110,235,369".split(',')
  ["6", "11", "32", "110", "235", "369"]
```

And if you want them be a number:

```
> "6,11,32,110,235,369".split(',').map(Number)
  [6, 11, 32, 110, 235, 369]
```

Answer (score 1):

Equal the string to a variable, and then use the `split()` method.

```
string.split(',');
```

Comment: The array has to be numbers, not strings.

Answer (score -1):

Let's take a look at the following example. You will have a better understanding of the whole process of converting string into array. You can copy and paste the code to see if that works.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <body>

<p id="demo">Click the button to display the array values after the split.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<script>
function myFunction()
    {
      var strValue = "How are you doing today?";
     var StrToArray = str.split("");
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=res;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```